# Having problems with a query in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm building my first app within Django and I'm trying to query a "load" based on the company that i've attached to the load. Here's the model in question.

```
class Load(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(UserCompany, null=True, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    load_number = models.IntegerField()
    carrier = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    pickup_date = models.DateField()
    delivery_date = models.DateField()
    shipper = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    consignee = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    po_number = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    pu_number = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    pieces = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.TextField()
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.date_created = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.load_number)
```

Now I'm trying to display a list on a page, but only display the loads attached to a specific company. The user needs to be attached to that company as well so here are my user models.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class UserCompany(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.company_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company_name

# User Model
class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # Additional Classes
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics', 
    blank=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(UserCompany, 
    null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Then i'm trying to query the "loads" within this view.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.shortcuts import redirect
import datetime
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils import timezone
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import View, DetailView
from easy_pdf.views import PDFTemplateResponseMixin
from loads.models import Load
from .forms import LoadForm
from users.models import UserCompany, UserProfileInfo

# Create your views here.

class PDFUserDetailView(PDFTemplateResponseMixin, DetailView):
    model = Load
    template_name = 'loads/load_pdf.html'

def load_list(request):
    loads = 
Load.objects.filter(company=request.company).order_by('date_created')
    return render(request, 'loads/load_list.html', {'loads':loads})
```

I was able to get the query working based on the user, so my thought is that this query would be the same. This is not the case.  I have a feeling that i'm referencing company wrong and maybe I somehow need to filter 2 more levels down all the way to the original UserCompany class, just not sure how to accomplish that.

The error that i'm getting is:

```
AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'company'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request.company` isn't a thing you can do. Instead of

```
Load.objects.filter(company=request.company).order_by('date_created')
```

You try something like this:

```
current_user = request.user
company = current_user.userprofileinfo.company
Load.objects.filter(company=company).order_by('date_created')
```

`request` just holds information about the current request which you can read more about [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/)

Comment: wow, thank you so much that worked perfectly. So the actual problem is that I was not defining company properly within the view.

That also explains why I was able to get it working with the user but not the company.